# Como criar e acessar um Array com Usuário e Permissão

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando criar um Array com usuários e permissões
Exemplo:

```
<?php
$adm_list = [
'login1' => '*',
'login2' => 'delete,update,insert',
];
?>
```

Gostaria de saber como verifica se meu usuário da sessão está nesta array E SE estive, obter as permissões

Pensei em algo do tipo, mas acredito que a logica não esteja correta

```
if($adm = array_search($session['login'], $adm_list){
$permissions = explode(',',$adm);
...
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seguindo essa ideia, o código abaixo faz as verificações para identificar se o usuário está na lista, conforme o seguinte:

1. Como o array `$permissoes` é multidimensional, tendo como chave o login, utilizei a função `array_key`, para obter um array apenas com os logins permitidos.
2. No array resultante (`$permitidos`) fiz uma busca pelo login desejado através da função `array_search`. O retorno desta será **ou** um número inteiro que indica a posição (no caso da busca encontrar o elemento no array); **ou** um boolean `FALSE`, no caso de não encontrar.
3. Como neste caso é indiferente saber exatamente a posição, basta verificar se esta é um número inteiro através da função `is_numeric` passando a posição do elemento encontrado.
4. Se de fato a posição for um número, e portanto o usuário procurado é autorizado. É feita a identificação das permissões, através da função `explode` na string que traz as permissões

```php
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!
$permissoes = [
    'login1' => '*'
    , 'login2' => 'insert,delete,update'
    , 'login3' => 'insert,update'
];

$usuario_atual = 'login2'; //$_SESSION
$permitidos = array_keys($permissoes); // passo 1
$indice = array_search($usuario_atual, $permitidos); // passo 2
$usuario_permitido = is_numeric($indice); //  passo 2 (continuação) 

if($usuario_permitido){ // passo 4
    $permissoes_usuario = explode(",", $permissoes[$usuario_atual]); // passo 4 (continuação)
    print_r($permissoes_usuario); //retorno mostrado abaixo
}else{
    //usuario não tem permissão
    $permissoes_usuario = false;
}
```

O código acima retorna o seguinte:

```
(
    [0] => insert
    [1] => delete
    [2] => update
)
```

Você pode reduzir alguns passos, como por exemplo...

```php
if(is_numeric(array_search($usuario_atual, array_keys($permissoes)))){
   $permissoes_usuario = explode(",", $permissoes[$usuario_atual]);
}
```

... mas, a legibilidade será sacrificada com isso, portanto fica o alerta.

Comment: perfeito, obrigado pela ajuda.